# Recording busy network traffic with tcpdump

Tags: mysql, sed, fifo, tcpdump

I have set up a system on my Raspberry Pi to record some TCPDUMP data. This system works under a light workload, but for some unknown reason, doesn't work under my "heavy" traffic (27 relevant packets per second).

Under the last heavy traffic system I tried to record, my monitor.log file had 35,200 rows that only contained the last 16 minutes worth of data (judging by the timestamps). My filter.log also only goes back 16 minutes worth. There should be something like 1 million rows.

Could anyone advise on how to find the possible bug, bottle-necks, dropped pipe data, etc?

RC.LOCAL:

```
java -jar filter.jar > filter.log 2>&1 &
bash ./monitor &
```

MONITOR:

```
TCPDUMP -l | SED | tee monitor.log | tee myFIFO
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to tee 2 files in this command. TCPDUMP -l | SED > monitor.log &  than a tail -f monitor.log | tee myFIFO give maybe more ressource for the main process with sed

Answer (score 0):

You may try an utility like `iptraf` to monitor traffic.

Answer (score 0):

try sed with stream option (unbuffered) ( `-u` on aix and `--unbuffered` on GNU sed) so sed does not wait for an EOF or assimilate (like a >> file from a discontinu stream)

Comment: I tried to hide some of the details, which comprised of tcpdump and sed's flags to line buffer. Buffering was a problem I believe I fixed earlier on.